# Facebook SDK 4.0 - Composer Not Finding Repository

Tags: facebook-graph-api, composer-php

I'm trying to download the facebook/php-sdk-v4 repository into my project, running the "php composer.phar update" command.

I recently added this to the require section of my composer.json file:
"facebook/php-sdk-v4": "4.0.*",

Upon running the update command, I am given the following error:
---> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
      Problem 1
      - The requested package facebook/php-sdk-v4 1.0.0 could not be found.

It seems that I have set it up exactly according to the Facebook Graph API instructions as listed on this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

But... It's still unable to find the repository.

Does anybody know the name of the Facebook SDK 4.0 repository or see any reason why this process I am following isn't working?

Thanks for listening!

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/facebook/php-sdk-v4 indicates that the current version of facebook/php-sdk-v4 is `4.0.11`, not `1.0.0` (which appears never to have existed for that package). It's possible one of your other packages has an incorrect dependency on `1.0.0` - your entire `composter.json` would help.

Comment: This is what the json file looks like:

Comment: {
    "name": "facebook/php-sdk-v4",
    "description": "Facebook SDK for PHP",
    "keywords": ["facebook", "sdk"],
    "type": "library",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4",
    "license": "Facebook Platform",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Facebook",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/contributors"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
     "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "*",
     "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "4.0.*",

Comment: "php": ">=5.4",
     "psr/log": "1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": ">=4.0.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "Allows for implementation of the Guzzle HTTP client"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Facebook\\": "src/Facebook/",
            "FacebookAds\\": "src/FacebookAds/"
        }
    }
}